# Manually launch OpenMPI jobs

Tags: cluster-computing, openmpi, hpc

I have a cluster that does not allow direct ssh access, but does permit me to submit commands through a proprietary interface.

Is there any way to either manually launch OpenMPI jobs, or documentation on how to write a custom launcher?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without breaking some kind of agreement.

I assume you have some kind of a web-based interface that allows you to fill certain fields and maybe upload data. Or something similar. What this interface will probably do - is it's going to generate a request/file for a scheduler. Most likely, [SGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine) or [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System). The direct access to the cluster is limited in order to

- organize task priorities and order
- prevent users from hogging the machines
- make it easier to launch complicated tasks requiring complicated machine(s) configuration

So, you, effectively, want to go around a scheduler. I don't think you can or you should.

However, usually, the clusters have so-called, head nodes which would allow SSH access to them. These nodes would serve as a place to submit scheduler requests from them and, maybe, do small compilation/result processing (with very limited resources). Such configuration would eliminate the web interface but still leaves a very important scheduler for a cluster that is used by many people concurrently.